# iPhone SDK: how to play music and record from the mic at the same time?

Tags: iphone, audio, media-player, microphone

I am trying to play music from the user's music library and at the same time record from the built-in microphone. However, as soon as I start recording from the microphone it automatically pauses the music, and I can't find any way to play music and record at the same time. I am using the MediaPlayer framework to play music and the AudioToolbox framework to record from the mic.

Does anyone know if it is possible to play music and record from the mic at the same time, and if so how to do it?

Comment: I doubt the iPhone would allow this, as it may make pirating music too easy ;-).

Answer (score 3):

You set your audio session to `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord`
 and create an in/out remote io audio unit.

The "loopy" author talks about how to do this [here](http://michael.tyson.id.au/2008/11/04/using-remoteio-audio-unit/) and provides code.
The trailblazing tones of the article are slightly dated now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set your audiosession properties to allow both recording and playback. This might mean that you need to use AudioToolbox for the playback as well as the recording.

Answer (score 0):

try:

> Add #import "CDAudioManager.h"to AppDelegate.m and Add [CDAudioManager
>   initAsynchronously:kAMM_PlayAndRecord]; to - (void)
>   applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application